# Error a la hora de moficar una fecha en Java con SQL server : Incorrect syntax near ' '

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, netbeans, prepared-statements

Estoy realizando un sistema el cual permita modificar los registros que estan en mi bdd SQL al seleccionar el registro en mi Jtable, al seleccionar el registro en mi jtable la fecha se pasa a un datechooser y otros campos a los textfield, cuando le doy al botón modificar me sale error syntax near '' y la fecha que selecciono como modificacion. El datechooser utiliza java.util.date por lo que en mi metodo modificar lo paso a un sql date para poder modificarlo pero aun asi me marca el error creo que estoy equivocandome en alguna comilla en mi preparedStatement pero no logro detectar el problema, tengo varios dias atorado con este problema les dejo el código de mi botón modificar:

```
private void btnModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

        Polizas ps = new Polizas();

        int fila = tablaPorFechas.getSelectedRow();
        String valor = tablaPorFechas.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString();
        ps.NombrePoliza = valor;
        
        
        
        java.util.Date utilStartDate = dateChooserFechaMod.getDate();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());
        
        ps.Fecha = sqlDate;
        ps.TipoPol = txtTipo.getText();
        ps.Concepto = txtConcepto.getText();
        ps.IdDiario = txtDiario.getText();

        Control control = new Control();
        control.actualizar(ps.NombrePoliza, ps.Fecha, ps.TipoPol, ps.Concepto, ps.IdDiario);
        mostrarDatos();


    }
```

Y el codigo de mi metodo actualizar:

```
public void actualizar(String NombrePoliza, Date Fecha, String TipoPol, String Concepto, String IdDiario) {
        try {
            Polizas ps = new Polizas();

            ps.NombrePoliza = NombrePoliza;
            ps.Fecha = Fecha;
            ps.TipoPol = TipoPol;
            ps.Concepto = Concepto;
            ps.IdDiario = IdDiario;

            Conexion.getConexion();

            PreparedStatement update = Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement("UPDATE tabla1 set Fecha '" + ps.Fecha + "', 'yyyy-MM-dd' , TipoPol = '" + ps.TipoPol + "', Concepto = '" + ps.Concepto + "',IdDiario = '" + ps.IdDiario + "' WHERE NombrePoliza= '" + ps.NombrePoliza + "'");
            update.executeUpdate();

            FrmGenerar frm = new FrmGenerar();
            frm.mostrarDatos();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se actualizo correctamente");
            Conexion.getConexion().close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);

        }
    }
```

Aqui es donde me marca el error,

> Error:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:IncorrectSyntaxNear'2022-03-05' la fecha es la que yo selecciono en mi datechooser como nueva fecha a modificar.[image: Error que me manda cuadno le doy al boton modificar]

Mi consulta en Sql:

```
"UPDATE tabla1 set Fecha '" + ps.Fecha + "', 'yyyy-MM-dd' , TipoPol = '" + ps.TipoPol + "', Concepto = '" + ps.Concepto + "',IdDiario = '" + ps.IdDiario + "' WHERE NombrePoliza= '" + ps.NombrePoliza + "'");
```

Comment: Parece que falta un signo de igual después de `set Fecha `

Comment: Más allá de tu error, tu código está abierto a inyección de SQL. Necesitas parametrizar tus instrucciones de SQL y es mejor aún si las conviertes en procedimientos almacenados.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, estas en lo correcto me faltaba el signo de igual, y gracias por el otro comentario, empezare a trabajar en convertirlo en un procedimiento almacenado, abrazo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema mayor en tu código no es el error de sintaxis, sino el grave riesgo que supondría escribir y ejecutar con éxito una consulta con datos proporcionados por el usuario, porque un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular los datos y causar graves daños en el sistema, sustraer datos sensibles, acceder a privilegios que no le son concedidos, etc.

La solución sería **escribir una consulta preparada real**, la cual lleva unos marcadores que luego pasarías usando el método adecuado. Así resolverás tu problema de seguridad y de paso, el error de sintaxis desaparecerá, pues es un falso problema.

Te muestro la parte del código que deberías cambiar:

```
/*
   Las consultas preparadas consisten en dos cosas:
     1. En lugar de los valores, pones un marcador ?
     2. Usas un método set del tipo de dato, poniendo además la posición para cada dato
*/
String sql="UPDATE tabla1 SET Fecha = ?, TipoPol = ?, Concepto = ?, IdDiario = ? WHERE NombrePoliza = ?";
    PreparedStatement update = Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);
    update.setDate  (1, Fecha);
    update.setString(2, TipoPol);
    update.setString(3, Concepto);
    update.setString(4, IdDiario);
    update.setString(5, NombrePoliza);
    update.executeUpdate();

    //Resto del ćodigo
```

Para más detalles sobre consultas preparadas, consulta la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

### Post-Data

NÓTESE que aquí yo he usado las variables directamente. En tu código metes esa información dentro de un objeto `Polizas`, pero eso, al menos en ese contexto, no tiene demasiado sentido, a no ser que uses ese objeto posteriormente.

En tu código se aprecia que estás usando mal la POO, la cual existe, entre otras cosas, **para reutilizar código**, tú haces lo contrario, algo así como una POO invertida. Es decir, antes de llamar a `actualizar` creas tu objeto `Polizas` y lo informas con los datos. Pero luego, en `actualizar` creas ooootro objeto, y lo informas con los datos que pasaste en parámetro:

```
        Polizas ps = new Polizas();

        ps.NombrePoliza = NombrePoliza;
        ps.Fecha = Fecha;
        ps.TipoPol = TipoPol;
        ps.Concepto = Concepto;
        ps.IdDiario = IdDiario;
```

Esto es absurdo. Es mucho mejor pasar en parámetro a `actualizar` la instancia del objeto `Polizas` que llenaste anteriormente.

También, debes ser cuidadoso con el uso de tus objetos. Por ejemplo, podrías estar conectando dos veces.

Aquí:

```
Conexion.getConexion();
```

Y luego aquí:

```
PreparedStatement update = Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement("...");
```

Si, en este contexto vas a usar la conexión una sola vez, entonces bastaría con la segunda llamada. En cambio, si vas a usar la conexión más de una vez, crea una referencia a la misma, y usa esa referencia:

```
Connection cn = Conexion.getConexion();
// Usar cn para una cosa
// ...
// Usar cn para otra cosa
// ...
// Usar cn para otra cosa, etc
```

Si quieres mejorar tu código totalmente, puedes hacer algo así:

```
private void btnModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

        Polizas ps = new Polizas();

        int fila = tablaPorFechas.getSelectedRow();
        String valor = tablaPorFechas.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString();
        ps.NombrePoliza = valor;       
        
        java.util.Date utilStartDate = dateChooserFechaMod.getDate();
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilStartDate.getTime());
        
        ps.Fecha = sqlDate;
        ps.TipoPol = txtTipo.getText();
        ps.Concepto = txtConcepto.getText();
        ps.IdDiario = txtDiario.getText();

        Control control = new Control();
        /*
           OJO: Cambiaremos la signatura del método actualizar
           ahora le pasaremos la instancia de Polizas
          ¡que para esto es la POO!
        */
        control.actualizar(ps);
        mostrarDatos();

    }
```

---

Ahora modificamos el método  `actualizar()` del siguiente modo:

```
public void actualizar(Polizas ps) {
        try {
            /*
               TODO esto sobra ...
            Polizas ps = new Polizas();
            ps.NombrePoliza = NombrePoliza;
            ps.Fecha = Fecha;
            ps.TipoPol = TipoPol;
            ps.Concepto = Concepto;
            ps.IdDiario = IdDiario;
            */

            /*
               Esto también sobra ...
               al menos para este caso          
            Conexion.getConexion();
            */

            String sql="UPDATE tabla1 SET Fecha = ?, TipoPol = ?, Concepto = ?, IdDiario = ? WHERE NombrePoliza = ?";
            PreparedStatement update = Conexion.getConexion().prepareStatement(sql);

            /*
               OJO, usaremos la instancia ps
               para obtener cada dato
               SUPONGO que tienen su método getter para cada propiedad,
              los nombres de método los IMAGINO
              si no acierto en alguno lo cambias
             */
            update.setDate  (1, ps.getFecha());
            update.setString(2, ps.getTipoPol());
            update.setString(3, ps.getConcepto());
            update.setString(4, ps.getIdDiario());
            update.setString(5, ps.getNombrePoliza());
            update.executeUpdate();


            FrmGenerar frm = new FrmGenerar();
            frm.mostrarDatos();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se actualizo correctamente");
            Conexion.getConexion().close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: " + e);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Correcto, Muchísimas Gracias por su ayuda empezare a trabajar en crear la consulta en un procedimiento almacenado, saludos..

Comment: @GILDARDOORTEGAPROAÑO revisa la respuesta editada. El uso que haces de la POO tampoco es correcto. Aquí lo propio sería cambiar la signatura de `actualizar`, pasándole un objeto `Polizas`  en parámetro y trabajar dentro del método con ese objeto.